# while(true) + Task.Delay() inside async void method; should I expect trouble?

Tags: .net, wpf, async-await

Instead of manually fiddling with a DispatcherTimer I came up with this:

```
    public async void StartWatching()
    {
        Debug.Assert(SynchronizationContext.Current is DispatcherSynchronizationContext, "SynchronizationContext.Current is DispatcherSynchronizationContext");
        while ( true )
        {
            this.GC0 = GC.CollectionCount(0);
            this.GC1 = GC.CollectionCount(1);
            this.GC2 = GC.CollectionCount(2);
            this.RAM = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
            await Task.Delay(1500);
        }
    }
```

**This code is not about garbage collection but just showing statistics on a status bar.**

This gets started once (from within `Application.OnStartup`) and is intended to run for the entire application runtime.

## Single question

Will me get this into any kind of trouble when running long term (weeks)?

Comment: Why do you *need* to initiate the garbage collection manually?

Comment: @MikeEason I'm just showing statistics on a status bar.

Comment: Where's the problem with a timer? This is THE use case for timers, why do you need an alternative?

Comment: Well, you are *specifically* doing something that will consume resources (unnecessary), every 1.5 seconds, this will reduce the performance of your application.

Comment: @JeffRSon If I rewrite the `Debug.Assert` to `SynchronizationContext.Current != null` the code becomes technology agnostic and could be used across WPF, Winforms, Xamarin, Mobile, etc.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen using a Timer this would be the same. If I wanna see permanently updating statistics I have to accept this cannot be done without a cost.

Comment: @springy76: What about System.Threading.Timer? You would encapsulate UI thread switches (Invoke etc) in your UI specific code.

Comment: @JeffRSon I value your effort but I know how to use all sort of timers and manual synchronization primitives. I just want to know if this code is harmful and if yes then why.

Answer (score 2):

> Will me get this into any kind of trouble when running long term (weeks)?

Not really. There are some things to be aware of, though.

Since your method returns `async void`, any exceptions will be raised directly on the `SynchronizationContext` that was current at the beginning of the method. So, they'll go straight to the dispatcher (or application for WinForms). It sounds like this behavior may be what you *want*.

Doing work followed by a delay is different than using a periodic timer, especially if the work can take different amounts of time. So, this code won't run every 1.5 seconds; it'll be a little less often than that. However, the *benefit* from doing it this way is that you don't have to worry about overlapping code, like you do with a purely periodic timer.

There'll also be more "jitter". What happens under the covers is that `Task.Delay` starts a *thread pool* timer, and when that fires, then it'll complete the task; at that point, the continuation for `StartWatching` is *scheduled* to the UI thread, and it will patiently wait for the UI thread to be free before executing its work. So there'll be an additional "wait for the UI thread" that will take a variable amount of time - usually immediate, but sometimes waiting for all your UI bindings to update, ...

Finally, very small delays may not work well. The WinForm and Dispatcher timers use more advanced mechanisms (built right into their message loops) to get more accuracy. Due to the additional overhead of `Task.Delay`, I believe that in a real-world app, it will not work for very small delays. (This is just a gut feeling, not the result of testing).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think there is anything particularly bad about this method, compared to the use of `DispatcherTimer`. Personally, I used this method as well - it is very short, and straight to the point.

However, note that `async` methods do not crash your application - they silently die without you knowing. Therefore you need to catch all possible exceptions you can think of. Also, any `finally` blocks within `async` methods would not run as well. You should also consider adding `CancellationToken` to it as well.

For your case, I don't see that would cause problem.

Comment: I cannot confirm this: Exceptions thrown both before or after `await` luckily bubble up to `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` event. Isn't this the speciality about `async VOID`?